# Does <td> have the same line-height as its height?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, tablecell

I am trying to make the texts both horizontal and vertical alignment inside a div. I have 2 ways of doing it:

1. Set the line-height of a div the same value as its height:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   div {
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    line-height: 400px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <div>This is the contents.</div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

2. Change the display of a div to table-cell:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div><p>This is the contents.</p></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Both methods work. It looks like there's a connection between them. And `display: table-cell;` is to make an element display as a `<td>`. So my question is: Does `<td>` have the same line-height as its height?

Comment: TD has the special feature of vertical-align property. It's nothing to do with line-height. If you add more content into the P make sure it starts wrapping, you'll see the big difference between the two methods.

Comment: Hi @Pangloss , thanks. So you mean not every element has the vertical-align property? I thought it applies to every container.

Comment: That's right, it only works on certain elements. it is a very confusing property. Sometimes it applies to the element itself (i.e. inline elements), sometimes it applies to the inner elements/content (i.e. TD). I would recommend you google "how vertical align works", and follow some detailed explanations.

Comment: Hi @Pangloss , ah, I see. I just found this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align which says that "The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box." That explains everything, I think. Thanks so much for your nice help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: To answer the question in the title: no, a table cell does not have the same line height as its height.

<sub>Of course it can have the same height as its line height, in some circumstances, but that's not what you asked.</sub>

Then the question in the post itself.
If you're sure the content is a single line of text, then solution #1 is the simplest. You won't even have to set the height of the div; setting the line height is enough.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px; /* acts the same with or without height:100px */
}
```

```html
<div>This is the contents.</div>
```

However, if the content may consist of more than one line, and you want to keep the same total height, you can't use `line-height`. `display:table-cell` is one possibility, at least if you also set `vertical-align`, as you noticed. (See snippet #2 in the question.)

Or, you can an additional block element inside the div and use positioning to place it in the middle.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
}
div p {
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%; top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div><p>This is the contents<br>and more contents.</p></div>
```

One more remark about table cells: please note that real table cells (<td> and <th>) have `vertical-align:middle` for a default, while other elements like <div> have `vertical-align:baseline`. So if you give a <div> `display:table-cell`, you will also have to give it `vertical-align:middle`, otherwise it won't behave like a real table cell does. (Setting one property doesn't change other properties automatically.)